# Change the header window color of an installer in inno setup

Tags: inno-setup

I create a simple installer using inno setup, and I set the background color in the installer as shown in the image.

[image: simple inno-setup installer]

Is it also possible to change the color of the window title to match the color of the installer body?

Comment: Hardly. Most likely not with the plain Inno Setup API. It's very difficult to do, even if you had a full control of the window. What you do not have in Inno Setup API. Maybe if you implement some external DLL. – Bad idea anyway. Do not do that.

Comment: I saw that in the TSetupForm form it is possible to completely remove the title, with the  property `BorderStyle := bsNone`
Maybe there is an option to behave with WizardForm similarly?
Or, if it's not too complicated, replace WizardForm with SetupForm?
(My installer only has 2 pages)

Comment: Of course there is. `WizardForm.BorderStyle := bsNone` – But that's bad user experience.

Comment: OK. Thanks for the help. I will just note that the way the installer appears in the image is not final, and the `BoredrStyle` property may be appropriate for me.